# What Installer does Python.org use for python 2.7?

Tags: python, installation

I'm curious because from 2.7.11 it is incorrectly calculating/using an incorrect Windows/NTFS short name (which causes the installation to fail). It tries to use a ~1 shortname when the actual folder has a ~2 shortname.

The 2.7.10 installer is working correctly, so it was either an update to the installer version, or to the installer script. Either way, my question is:

What Installer does Python.org use for python 2.7?

Comment: why are you installing 2.7 in 2019?

Comment: @SuperStew Because it's still 20 days until 2020, and I'd like to get it done before Christmas.